# Using a Firebase Access Token with the Picker API

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication, google-picker

I am trying to open the Google Picker API in a React application. I am using Firebase for authentication, so I thought I could use the accessToken generated to accomplish that, but it is opening a page requesting that I signed in. Here is the code I am using in the component trying to open the picker. Only very slightly modified from the guide.

```
  loadPicker() {
    window.gapi.load('picker', {callback: this.pickerLoaded});
  }

  pickerLoaded() {
    this.state.user.getToken()
      .then(token => {
        if (token) {
          const developerKey = 'AIzaSyAmVIH3Gu3pP2VKlrgVme9YJe30GQCDEh8';
          let picker = new window.google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .addView(window.google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
            .setOAuthToken(token)
            .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
            .setOrigin(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host)
            .setCallback((data) => console.log(data))
            .build();

          picker.setVisible(true);
        }
      });
  }

  pickerCallback(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
```

I am hoping that I don't need to load the auth service from the Google API also since the access token already exists. Is there a method that I need to use to set that token that I am not seeing, besides the .setOAuthToken() method on the PickerBuilder()?

Thanks for any consideration.